# JavaFX Alert not showing up when performing a fields check on a Dialog

Tags: javafx

I am a beginner in JavaFX and practicing on a small application. The issue is I am trying without success to implement a check of a Dialog fields if empty, and if so to populate an Alert of type WARNING.
The dialog is indeed not entering data if all fields are not filled, but the alert never shows up.

This the main controller code :

```
  @FXML
    public void showAddReportDialog () {
        Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<ButtonType>();
        dialog.initOwner(mainPanel.getScene().getWindow());
        dialog.setTitle("Add new report");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("addReportDialog.fxml"));
        try {
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load the dialog");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        final Button btOK = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        btOK.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            AddDialogController addDialogController = fxmlLoader.getController();
            Report newReport = addDialogController.getNewReport();
            if (newReport != null) {
                data.addReport(newReport);
                data.saveReports();
            } else {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    }
```

And this is the Dialog Controller code including alert :

```
public Report getNewReport() {
  String iD = iDField.getText();
  String name = nameField.getText();
  LocalDate dueDate = dueDateField.getValue();
  String recipients = recipientsField.getText();
  String notes = notesField.getText();

  String dueDateString = dueDate.toString();

  if (iDField.getText().equals("") || nameField.getText().equals("") || dueDateField.getValue() == null || recipientsField.getText().equals("") || notesField.getText().equals("")) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.setTitle("Fields incomplete");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Please complete all the form fields");
    alert.showAndWait();
    return null;
  } else {
    Report newReport = new Report(iD, name, dueDateString, recipients, notes);
    return newReport;
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using but the `Dialog` will always close after the `Alert` is closed. I would recommend binding the login `Button` to the `TextFields`.

**Answer to your question:**

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        Button button = new Button("Show Add Report Dialog");
        button.setOnAction((e) -> {
            showAddReportDialog();
        });

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public void showAddReportDialog () {
        //Code from https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/.
        Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Login Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Look, a Custom Login Dialog");

        // Set the icon (must be included in the project).
        //dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView(this.getClass().getResource("login.png").toString()));

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Login", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        // Create the username and password labels and fields.
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField username = new TextField();
        username.setPromptText("Username");
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
        password.setPromptText("Password");

        grid.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(username, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(password, 1, 1);

        // Enable/Disable login button depending on whether a username was entered.
        Node loginButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(loginButtonType);
        //loginButton.setDisable(true);

        // Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
//        loginButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
//            () -> username.getText().isEmpty() || password.getText().isEmpty(),
//            username.textProperty(), password.textProperty()));

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        // Request focus on the username field by default.
        Platform.runLater(() -> username.requestFocus());

        // Convert the result to a username-password-pair when the login button is clicked.
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == loginButtonType) {
                if(username.getText().isBlank() || password.getText().isBlank())
                {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setTitle("Fields incomplete");
                    alert.setHeaderText(null);
                    alert.setContentText("Please complete all the form fields");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Pair<String, String>(username.getText(), password.getText());
                }
                
            }
            
            return null;
        });

        Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

        result.ifPresent(usernamePassword -> {
            System.out.println("Username=" + usernamePassword.getKey() + ", Password=" + usernamePassword.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

**What I recommend: Use `Bindings`**

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        Button button = new Button("Show Add Report Dialog");
        button.setOnAction((e) -> {
            showAddReportDialog();
        });

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public void showAddReportDialog () {
        //Code from https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/.
        Dialog<Pair<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Login Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Look, a Custom Login Dialog");

        // Set the icon (must be included in the project).
        //dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView(this.getClass().getResource("login.png").toString()));

        // Set the button types.
        ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Login", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

        // Create the username and password labels and fields.
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

        TextField username = new TextField();
        username.setPromptText("Username");
        PasswordField password = new PasswordField();
        password.setPromptText("Password");

        grid.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
        grid.add(username, 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(password, 1, 1);

        // Enable/Disable login button depending on whether a username was entered.
        Node loginButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(loginButtonType);
        loginButton.setDisable(true);

        // Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
        loginButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> username.getText().isEmpty() || password.getText().isEmpty(),
            username.textProperty(), password.textProperty()));

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

        // Request focus on the username field by default.
        Platform.runLater(() -> username.requestFocus());

        // Convert the result to a username-password-pair when the login button is clicked.
        dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
            if (dialogButton == loginButtonType) {               
                return new Pair<>(username.getText(), password.getText());
            }
            
            return null;
        });

        Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

        result.ifPresent(usernamePassword -> {
            System.out.println("Username=" + usernamePassword.getKey() + ", Password=" + usernamePassword.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Binding helps, and I figured out that my alert was not showing up because of the validation of the Dialog fields. When I used  : if ((iDField.getText() == null || iDField.getText().trim().isEmpty())   instead of  : if(iDField.getText().equals("")), the alert worked !